# TCP Client/Server program getting stuck when

Tags: java

I have been working on creating a program where communication can be exchanged between a server and a client using to program files in java. However, when I try to send messages from server to client. I have been working on a project where I am trying to send a message from a server to a client. However, when I put in my message, from the server, the client seems to get stuck on `sentence = inFromServer.readLine();` in the client portion of my code and I'm not sure why. I ran the debugger on this, and it seems that "sentence" takes in the value that was inputted from the client, so im not sure why it get stuck. Does anyone have an idea what the problem may be?
Here's my code for reference-
Server Code:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
class threading implements Runnable {
    private int portnumbers;
    Socket clientsocket;
    ServerSocket connectorsocket;

    public threading(Socket clientsocket)
    {
        this.clientsocket = clientsocket;
    }
    
    public void run(){
        try {
            Serverstuff(this.clientsocket);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.print("I found exception" + ex);
        }
    }

    public void Serverstuff(Socket socketlol)
    {
       // File h = null;
        int width = 1536;
        int height = 2048;
        BufferedImage image = null;
        File f = null;
        while(true) {
            try {
                String sentence1;
                //Wait on welcoming socket for client
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketlol.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socketlol.getOutputStream());//create input stream, attached to socket
                System.out.println("Flag1");
                sentence1 = inFromUser.readLine();
                System.out.println("Flag2");
                System.out.println("Flag3");
                outToClient.writeBytes(sentence1);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.print("I found exception" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class server{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;

        int portnumber;
        Scanner scanney = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of clients");
        String arg1 = scanney.next();
        int arg2 = Integer.parseInt(arg1);
        int[] socketarray = new int[arg2];
        for(int i = 0; i < arg2; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter the port number");
            String portnumberstr = scanney.next();
            portnumber = Integer.parseInt(portnumberstr);
            socketarray[i] = portnumber;
        }
        //ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        int g = 0;
        int whatever;
        //ServerSocket welcomeSocket2 = new ServerSocket(5001);
        while (true) {
            if(g < arg2) {
                System.out.println("Flagwhile1");
                whatever = socketarray[g];
                ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(whatever);
                System.out.println("Flagwhile2");
                Socket clientsock = welcomeSocket.accept();
                threading newthread = new threading(clientsock);
                System.out.println("Flagwhile3");
                new Thread(newthread).start();

                g = g + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class client2{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        try {
                String sentence;
                String modifiedSentence;
                BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //Create input stream

                Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.2", 5001); //Create client socket connect to server

                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); //Create output stream, attached to socket
                System.out.println("Flag19");
                BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); //Create input stream attached to socket
                System.out.println("Flag20");
                sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n'); //send line to server

                System.out.println("Flag21");
                sentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                System.out.println("Flag22");
                System.out.println(sentence);
                int test = 5;
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try 

outToClient.writeBytes(sentence1 + "\n");

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that was the problem I was having

Comment: Don't forget to upvote comment if it helped you :)